# Integer literal overflows when stored into 'UInt'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Updated xCode to 6.3 and/or Swift 1.2 and suddenly getting this error

> Integer literal overflows when stored into 'UInt'* pointing a red dot below at the Hex color `0x100114151`

Here is my code:

```
mybuttonOutLet.setTitleColor(UIColorFromRGB(0x100114151), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Here is my UIColorFromRGB() method

```
func UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue: UInt) -> UIColor {
    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thats wierd, I tried your code, and it works fine, did you try  cleaning the project and/or deletind the derrived data?

Comment: The problem has been explained below, but what color did you expect as the result?

Comment: http://s23.postimg.org/ecaroi4mf/image.png the white color in the image

Comment: I think you made a mistake by taking decimal RBG values and concatenated integers, and used them as hexadecimal literal . Hex RBG number of that color is something like `0x6D79DA`.

Comment: @Kirsteins is this color code of white ? i need white color.

Comment: @QadirHussain White is `0xFFFFFF`. You can use `UIColor.whiteColor()` for that.

Answer (score 1):

`0x100114151`. Okay, that's nine hex digits. Assumption: `UInt` is 32 bits on your platform. That works out to eight hex digits.

In other words, you are assigning a >32-bit value to a variable that can hold only 32 bits.